# Whether to use backbone routers/history

Tags: javascript, backbone.js, browser-history, backbone-routing

I'm creating a collection of backbone powered widgets (for lack of a better word). The consumers will drop the widgets into their web app and initialize them. I have the need to track history for certain pieces of the widgets but don't necessarily need/want to actually inject things into the browser's history *nor* update the URL. `.navigate`'s `replace` and `trigger` options seem useful. I do not want to interfere with whatever the app is presently doing with the URL / history of the browser unless they opt-in to do so (if at all).

1. Do not want to update the URL (unless opted in)
2. Do not want to insert events into the browsers history (unless opted in)
3. Do want to be able to track history (a simple array would probably be enough but being able to opt-in to item's 1 and 2 at will is a great benefit)

Does backbone's routers/history features seem like a fit for my use case or should I just roll my own solution?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Backbone router is probably NOT what you are looking for, unless you can guarantee that all of your consumers (and really that means all of your consumers' consumers) will have very modern browsers.  The reason is that, if the user *doesn't* have a modern browser, Backbone will fall back on using the URL to do the navigation, and your requirement #1 would get violated by that.

By "modern browser", what I mean is one that shows up as green here:

http://caniuse.com/#feat=history

If I were in your shoes I'd just use plain old cookies to store the navigation details; as long as there isn't much data involved I'd think that would work.